# What is the meaning of "dropped" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "dropped" in the following sentence?

> They ***dropped*** a report on the scheme. they claim the 4 masterminds atop the weapons network are Mr. A, Mr. B, Mr. C, and Mr. D.

Does "dropped" in the sentence mean "to submit a report on the scheme" ?
Or does "dropped" mean "to delete a report on the scheme"?

---

The content in the image where the word "dropped" is used.
(Source: https://americasbestpics.com/picture/no-one-is-reporting-on-this-russian-military-recently-dropped-bzlGHeDY9 )

[image]

Comment: This sentence on its own could mean almost anything. Could you please edit your question to provide more context: either a link to the place where you saw this sentence, or a complete paragraph containing the sentence.

Comment: This sentence is a sentence I made with reference to what I saw when i was googling. I saw it in the image, so now I can't find it even if I search with this sentence I remember. I will try to make a long sentence by remembering the structure of the sentence I saw.

Comment: It seems that the structure and content of the sentences I remember were roughly like this. What does "dropped" in the sentences mean?

Comment: It _could_ mean 'they abandoned the plan to publish a report on the scheme', but without knowing the context it's impossible to be sure.

Comment: Kate Bunting// If so, could it mean "they submitted the plan to publish a report on the scheme" ?

Comment: @user175012 Your last question makes little sense without further context. But it's most unlikely that you could interpret it that way. Kate's answer is by far the most probable interpretation.

Comment: i now found it -> https://americasbestpics.com/picture/no-one-is-reporting-on-this-russian-military-recently-dropped-bzlGHeDY9

Comment: "dropped" as used in the following sentences. What does "dropped" mean in " No one is reporting on this.... Russian military recently dropped a new finalized report on the entire US Biological weapons scheme... They claim the the 4 masterminds atop the biological weapons network are Barack Obama, Hilary Clinton, Joe Biden, and George Soros. As well as 12 other NATO countries knew of and assisted the US in this operation to develop biological weapons. They also include the US pharmaceutical companies Pfizer, "

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be asking the meaning of an example sentence (not particularly idiomatic) that the OP made up himself.

Comment: ..."dropped" is just a figurative usage alluding to the idiomatic standard *they **dropped a bombshell** on us* (metaphorical, meaning they did or communicated something completely unexpected, that we found extremely unsettling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No one is reporting on this.... Russian military recently **dropped** a new finalized report on the entire US Biological weapons scheme... They claim the the 4 masterminds atop the biological weapons network are Barack Obama, Hilary Clinton, Joe Biden, and George Soros. As well as 12 other NATO countries knew of and assisted the US in this operation to develop biological weapons.

[link](https://americasbestpics.com/picture/no-one-is-reporting-on-this-russian-military-recently-dropped-bzlGHeDY9)

*drop* in this context takes the following meaning in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drop)

> drop verb (BE/MAKE AVAILABLE)
> [ I or T ] informal

> to become available for people to buy, listen to, or watch, especially using the internet; to make something available like this:

> We heard that rapper Dave was about to drop a new album.